# gnuplot: add values above the bars

Tags: gnuplot

My script takes the data from the third and 5th columns of the input datafile considering only the lines where the value from the 5th column > 0.05, producing a bar graph

```
cat <<EOS | gnuplot > graph.png
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set xtics noenhanced
set xlabel "Fraction, %"
set ylabel "H-bond donor, residue"
set key off
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.9
plot "<awk 'NR == 1 || \$5 > 0.05' $file" using 0:5:xtic(3) with boxes
EOS
```

I need to modify my gnuplot ploting function to indicate the value corresponded to Y (Frac) above each bar on the plot. I've already tried to add using 1:2 with labels:

```
plot "<awk 'NR == 1 || \$5 > 0.05' $file" using 0:5:xtic(3) with boxes,\
     "<awk 'NR == 1 || \$5 > 0.05' $file" using 1:2:2 with labels
```